# Is the preprocessing process using the tfidf vectorizer really useful for model learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I am a student who is studying machine running alone.
As far as I know, the Tf-idf Vectorizer is a function that combines the Count Vectorizer and the Tf-idf Transformer.
I was wondering if the Tf-idf Transformer process could actually have a impact on the model learning process.
In my experience, there seemed to be no model performance difference between using CountVectorizer and Tf-idf Vectorizer in preprocessing String vector.
Is there a situation where we need to consider the Tf-idfVectorizer rather than the CountVectorizer when processing a String Vector?

Comment: If you're asking about a particular library, that's off-topic here.  "Tf-idf Vectorizer" might refer to some specific code in some particular machine learning library, but without context it isn't clear what you mean by that.

Comment: Anyway, yes, in some contexts TF-IDF does offer improvements.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf.